# PDF Details using python script

Tags: python

I would like to get details like Left, Top, Right and Bottom margins and comments from PDF file.  So when I input a PDF file name, script should give those details.

I am trying with Python-poppler in Windows.  It is taking too much time installing this using `conda install =c conda-forge poppler`.

**Can you suggest some good python library to do this using windows system?**

Comment: Perhaps PyPDF2?

Comment: Can you share an example file pdf?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PyPDF` library and here is a tutorial on [PyPDF reader](https://realpython.com/pdf-python/#history-of-pypdf-pypdf2-and-pypdf4)